# SQL Server stored procedure: issue merge two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I hope that someone will help you with the problems that I have. I want to merge two queries into one table in SQL Server. This is my procedure to which I arrived but in q2.[Umrli] ejected does not set data to be depends on q1.[Naziv Ustanove]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        q1.[Naziv ustanove], q1.[Broj lica], q1.[Broj dana lezanja], q2.Umrli
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             i_bolnica.naziv AS [Naziv ustanove], 
             COUNT (bolnickiracunSve.id) AS [Broj lica], 
             SUM(bolnickiracunSve.br_dana_lezanja) AS [Broj dana lezanja]
         FROM 
             i_bolnica 
         INNER JOIN 
             bolnickiracunSve ON i_bolnica.id = bolnickiracunSve.id_bolnica
         WHERE 
             bolnickiracunSve.id_bolnica < 91 
             AND bolnickiracunSve.id_odeljenje_otpust NOT IN (800,801,802) 
             AND bolnickiracunSve.id_drzavljanstvo IN (688)
             AND dbo.GrupeBolesti(bolnickiracunSve.id_osnovni_uzrok_hospitalizacije) NOT IN ('z%') 
         GROUP BY 
             i_bolnica.naziv)q1
    CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             i_bolnica.naziv AS [Naziv ustanove], 
             COUNT (bolnickiracunSve.id) AS [Umrli] 
         FROM 
             i_bolnica 
         INNER JOIN 
             bolnickiracunSve ON i_bolnica.id = bolnickiracunSve.id_bolnica
         WHERE 
             bolnickiracunSve.id_bolnica < 91 
             AND bolnickiracunSve.id_odeljenje_otpust NOT IN (800, 801, 802) 
             AND bolnickiracunSve.id_drzavljanstvo IN (688)
             AND dbo.GrupeBolesti(bolnickiracunSve.id_osnovni_uzrok_hospitalizacije) NOT IN ('z%') 
             AND bolnickiracunSve.id_vrsta_otpusta = '6'
         GROUP BY 
             i_bolnica.naziv)q2
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, the two subqueries are the same except for the `where` clause.  If so, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT b.naziv AS [Naziv ustanove], 
       COUNT(s.id) AS [Broj lica], 
        SUM(s.br_dana_lezanja) AS [Broj dana lezanja],
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.id_vrsta_otpusta = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM i_bolnica b INNER JOIN 
     bolnickiracunSve s
     ON b.id = s.id_bolnica
WHERE s.id_bolnica < 91 AND
      s.id_odeljenje_otpust NOT IN (800, 801, 802) AND
      s.id_drzavljanstvo IN (688) AND
      dbo.GrupeBolesti(s.id_osnovni_uzrok_hospitalizacije) NOT IN ('z%') 
GROUP BY b.naziv;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks Gordon this is solution and answer that I want to see, in my case this question is closed :)